# c# Adding a contact with Google Contacts API

Tags: c#, .net, google-contacts-api

I am trying to add a contact to Google Contacts using Google Contacts API using c# in Microsoft Visual Studios .net application.  My application is desktop, not being used on a website app.  I have already registered the application and have my client ID and secret.  I have the following code to add the contact but do not know how to send the post request and code for the token needed.  If I need to add any other using statements, please let me know.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

using System.IO;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;

public static Contact CreateContact(ContactsRequest cr)
    {
        Contact newEntry = new Contact();
        // Set the contact's name.
        newEntry.Name = new Name()
        {
            FullName = "Elizabeth Bennet",
            GivenName = "Elizabeth",
            FamilyName = "Bennet",
        };
        newEntry.Content = "Notes";
        // Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
        newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
        {
            Primary = true,
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
            Address = "liz@gmail.com"
        });
        newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
        {
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
            Address = "liz@example.com"
        });
        // Set the contact's phone numbers.
        newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Primary = true,
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
            Value = "(206)555-1212",
        });
        newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
            Value = "(206)555-1213",
        });
        // Set the contact's IM information.
        newEntry.IMs.Add(new IMAddress()
        {
            Primary = true,
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
            Protocol = ContactsProtocols.IsGoogleTalk,
        });
        // Set the contact's postal address.
        newEntry.PostalAddresses.Add(new StructuredPostalAddress()
        {
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
            Primary = true,
            Street = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
            City = "Mountain View",
            Region = "CA",
            Postcode = "94043",
            Country = "United States",
            FormattedAddress = "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View",
        });
        // Insert the contact.
        Uri feedUri = new 
        Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
        Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
        Console.WriteLine("Contact's ID: " + createdEntry.Id);
        return createdEntry;
    }

// create a new google contact
    private void btnGoogleContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // ...
        RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("TBF Database");
        // Add authorization token.
        // ...
        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
        // ...

        MessageBox.Show("Contact updated to Google Contacts", "Google 
        Contacts", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
```